# Binary Search through 2 Array

Tags: java, big-o, binary-search

i'm searching for duplicates between 2 arrays.

```
int[] f = {17,17,22,19};
int[] m = {21,19,24,22,20,23,18};
for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
    {
         for(int j = 0; j < f.length; j++)
        {
             if(m[i] == f[j])
            {
                System.out.printf(m[i] + " ");//showing common 
            }
        }
    }
```

currently my code is searching for it in n^2 however i'm trying to improve my codes to be running time complexity of O(LogN) instead of O(N^2). Is there a way which I can implement Binary Search algorithm to search between 2 Arrays?

Comment: Maybe sort the arrays first, and then compare them step by step. The comparision should be `O(n)` for `n = max(len(f), len(m))`

Comment: your current complexity is worst-case O(n^2) not O(n)

Comment: "*currently my code is searching for it linearly however i'm trying to improve my codes to be running time complexity of O(LogN) instead of O(N^2).*" - Since you have to visit each element at least once, the best time you can achieve is `O(n + m)` (given that `n` and `m` are the lengths of the arrays `f` and `m`).

Comment: You do not need to implement it. There is java.util.Arrays.binarySearch().

Comment: This page from geek for geeks should be much helpful https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-union-and-intersection-of-two-unsorted-arrays/ it solves this problem using different algorithms and discuss associated complexities

Answer (score 1):

You can create a set using the elements of the first array, then check if any of the elements in the second array are present in the set.

If the range of possible values is constrained, a direct-address table (a simple array with one index for each possible value) would be O(n).

Alternatively, using Java 8's HashSet (which degrades to a tree under collisions), operations are typically O(1) amortized and O(log n) in the worst case. So this would be O(n) or O(n log n) at worst.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, binary search is for sorted arrays. 
Secondly, even if you sort the arrays, sorting arrays have complexity O(nlog n) which is greater than below approach O(n).

Since you have to find duplicates Hashmap would come handy.
Hashmap put() has complexity of O(1) and it returns the old value associated with the key.

The below code has complexity of O(n)  where n is length of the longest array.
But this comes at the cost of extra space for the map.

```
    int[] f = {17, 17, 22, 19};
    int[] m = {21, 19, 24, 22, 20, 23, 18};
    Map<Integer, Integer> unique = new HashMap<>();

    for(int j = 0; j < f.length; j++) {
         unique.put(f[j], 1);
     }

    for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        Integer temp = unique.put(m[i], 2);
        if(temp != null && temp == 1) {

             System.out.printf(m[i] + " ");
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For given two array of length `f` and `m` I think the best approach can be to sort the bigger array say `m[]` using merge sort that will give complexity of `O(m*log(m))` and use binary search on sorted `m[]` for each element of `f[]` that will give complexity of `O(f*log(m))`. Worst case complexity will be around `O(log(m)*(m+f))`. If `f<<m` we are lucky!!

Answer (score 0):

You can reach **N log N**.

```
Arrays.sort(f); // Cost N log N.
Arrays.sort(m);
int fi = 0;
int mi = 0;
while (fi < f.length && mi < f.length) { // Cost N
    int c = Integer.compare(f[fi], m[mi]);
    if (c == 0) {
        System.out.printf("Duplicate %d.%n", f[fi]);
        ++fi;
        ++mi
    } else if (c < 0) {
        ++fi;
        // Speed improvement, unneeded heuristic:
        int ix = Array.binarySearch(f, fi, f.length);
        if (ix < 0) {
            fi = ~ix + 1; // Not found => insert position + 1.
        } else {
            fi = ix; // Found.
        }
    } else {
        ++mi;
        // Speed improvement, unneeded heuristic:
        int ix = Array.binarySearch(m, mi, f.length);
        if (ix < 0) {
            mi = ~ix + 1; // Not found => insert position + 1.
        } else {
            mi = ix; // Found.
        }
    }
}
```